# How to set From header to User email on Amazon SES?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon SES to send emails for my webapp.

Let's say user `user1@email.com` performs an action that sends an email to `user2@email.com`.

user2@email.com has an Auto-Reply that says he's out of office, and that emails should be forwarded instead to user3@email.com.

Emails from my webapp are sent from `no-reply@webapp.com` via SES (and I had to verify that I own that email.)

When sending the email from `user1@email.com` -> `user2@email.com`, I set From header to `no-reply@webapp.com` but Reply-To header is set to `user1@email.com`, in case further communication between these users is needed. This works if you hit the "Reply" button on the email, and instead of sending to no-reply, the email goes to user1. Good!

However...it seems that Auto-Reply functions in the vast majority of mail clients ignore the Reply-To field and only send the Auto-Reply email to the email in the "From" header.

So my question is: How do I "fake" the From header so that I can make it look like it's coming from `user1@email.com` so that Auto-Reply messages get delivered to the appropriate email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't looks like it's a good idea to make reply available to a noreply address, by concept...
Moving out from this is a good idea.
To allow SES to send email from any email in your domain(ie. *@email.com), you have to validate the domain itself(see [AWS Doc)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html)

Once it's done, you just have to put your sender email as the FROM field, just like you did with noreply. I don't know what language you are using but here is the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendEmail) using PHP SDK.

Comment: The problem with validating all from a domain is that registered users do not have an email from my domain. It could be gmail, yahoo, hotmail, or even their own custom domain. I need to be able to take any registered user's email, like "bob@gmail.com", and set that as the "From" header. Unfortunately, SES rejects this as I have no proof that I own that email, which I obviously do not, since it's a registered user's email, not mine.

Comment: Then you should be able to use the SDK of your favorite language to set the ReplyTo header parameter. Let me know if you have any details of the issue your are facing doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but if you read the original post:

**However...it seems that Auto-Reply functions in the vast majority of mail clients ignore the Reply-To field and only send the Auto-Reply email to the email in the "From" header**

Comment: Can you give an example of client ignoring this?

Comment: Outlook will ignore the reply-to header and instead will send vacation alerts/out of office messages to the "from" header